WooCommerce analytics is displaying 0 in the 'Items sold' field
I'm experiencing an issue with the Woocommerce analytics. Everything looks good except for the "Items Sold" field, which shows 0. Please refer to the attached screenshot.
I've attempted to clear the analytics cache, delete all action schedulers, and import all of the historical data.


